# Multiplication of matrices

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

I ve got two matrices W2 and hiddenLayer and i want to proceed the multiplication of those. W2  size's 12x50 and hiddenLayer size's 50x1. The proper code for the above calculation:

```
 for(int h=0; h<50; h++){
      for(int k=0; k<12; k++){
        outputLayer += W2[k][h]*HiddenLayer[h];
      }
}
```

or i ve got to put at first k-for??

Comment: Maybe `outputLayer[k]` or something like that. Perhaps you should switch the loops around; test both versions and profile.

Comment: The implication wasn't that you *had* to, but rather that one of the two orderings may be much faster than the other. You just have to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiplication [is defined as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Matrix_multiplication.2C_linear_equations_and_linear_transformations):

```
C = AB ⇔ Ci,j = Σk=1..n Ai,k Bk,j for i,j = 1...n (in case of square matrices).
```

Thus `outputLayer` is a vector. Since `HiddenLayer` is a vector too, this isn't really a matrix multiplication but a matrix vector multiplication, which simplifies the formula above:

```
b = Ax ⇔ bi = Σk=1..m Ai,k xk for i = 1...n (A is an n x m matrix).
```

So all in all your code should be something like

```
for(int row = 0; row < 12; row++){
    outputLayer[row] = 0;
    for(int column = 0;  column < 50; column++){    
        outputLayer[row] += W2[row][column]*HiddenLayer[column];
      }
}
```

Comment: Correct. But I'd also add one point. In the most general case multiplication of matrices contains 3 loops (in this case 2 loops, since one of the matrixes is actually a vector). Those 3 loops don't have to be nested in the order you've suggested, actually there are 6 varinats of how to order them. Since the matrix rows are usually consequent in memory, choosing the correct loop ordering utilizes the CPU cache more efficiently. One may multiply matrixes several times faster by reordering those loops. Of course this is relevant for large matrixes.

Comment: @valdo: This is true, however I wanted to keep the answer as simple as possible for OP. If you know that a specific matrix is always on the right hand side, you can even transpose the matrix and use `C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[j][k]`. There are many ways to speed up matrix-matrix-multiplications, but the asymptotic runtime is always O(n^(2,807)) (using Strassen's algorithm) or O(n^3) (using sequential multiplication and addition). Feel free to edit the answer if you want to :).